# How to use default jquery hide() method with jquery ui loaded?

Tags: jquery

My webpage has both jquery and jquery ui loaded, now I want to immediately hide a div, which can be easily done by default jquery method hide().

But jquery ui overwrites it with its own hide(), if jui's hide() is called without any argument, then it behaves just like the overwritten hide() and immediately hide the element;

But if I pass a callback function to the jui's hide(), the hide() method will hide the element with a unwanted default effect, which is quickly sliding left and disappearing.

My question is how to make jquery ui's hide() behave just same as jquery's hide() does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `0` for the duration of the effect, it won't occur.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/UBjK3/1/ (Tested in Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

just use `.css("display","none")` , or use `.hide('fade',0)`